# get object from Object in json android

Tags: android, arrays, json

[image]

How to Get object from verticals from json android.
I have got the vertical object.

```
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());

        Log.d(String.valueOf(obj),"obj");
```

want other 4 which are
health care
environmental care
agricultural product
consumer product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get JSON Objects from main object as follow:

1- Create Model classes for your JSON string. You can either use [jsonschema2pojo](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) or Android Plugins to create models classes for you.

2- Then follow this code

```
    Response response = new Gson().fromJson(loadJSONFromAsset(), Response.class);

    List<CartridgesItemItem> cartridges = response.getVerticals().getHealthCare().getCartridges();

    List<PackingRollsItemItem> packingRolls = response.getVerticals().getHealthCare().getPackingRolls();

    List<SterilizersItemItem> sterilizers = response.getVerticals().getHealthCare().getSterilizers();
```

where `Response` is my main model class created.

====================================================================

====================================================================

If you want to install plugin in Android Studio for converting JSON to model classes follow these steps:

1- You can go to Android Studio settings -> Plugins
2- search for **RoboPOJOGenerator** and install it
3- Then click on any package/folder on left side of your android studio

```
Select package -> new -> Generate POJO from JSON
```

See here

[image: Generating Pojo From Json Image]

4- Paste your Json string and Write name for your main class

See here

[image: Create Response class from json string]

5- Use above code mention in 2nd point for getting your string as model class (Response)

**Note:** you might need to add this dependency in build.gradle app

```
//GSON
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: just want healthcare , environmenatal care, agriculturecare, and consmercare to show. As i want to populate that in spinner . i am getting data of whole json of health care and vice versa

Comment: please share your complete json.

Comment: its too long ..

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1ElH4Y03Dpb6ukFX4GaZAKuu89I1LoK8l

Comment: 1. As per the json file provided,show 3 dropdown options namely : Verticals, Sub-Category and Products.
2. Product's dropdown should have suggestions option for search.     This are the things need to be done.. can u please help me.

Comment: updated my answer. Hope so it will be helpful !

Comment: not getting response.getverticals() , it is showing error

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create Model class with response:
https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
check this website. If you can not achieve your task then use any android studio plugin to create model classes.

Comment: cant make a pojo class , as the data is too large

Comment: no issue, you can create pojo class easily if data is large or small

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1ElH4Y03Dpb6ukFX4GaZAKuu89I1LoK8l                                           .can u make a pojo class. can u pls check

Comment: you can create pojo class to this website https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/. if you data is static and never change create a file and place into assests folder then read json file in android studio

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be to create a POJO class. The alternate solution to this would be to get Object from JSON and use it in your Model Object

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
JSONObject healthCare = obj.optJSONObject("Health Care")
```

This is just another way to get json object from JSON. POJO classes should be the way it is done as mentioned in the answer by @Ali Ahmed